# How to send address in Android Application to Google Maps

Tags: java, android, maps, street-address

Is there a way to set an address in an application so when it is clicked it automatically opens it in Google Maps? I may end up implementing Maps into my application but it is a simple reference app simply to find the address.

Comment: Check out the answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987551/how-to-open-google-maps-using-address

Answer (score 17):

You do this via an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

The various URI formats you can use are:

```
geo:latitude,longitude
geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom
geo:0,0?q=my+street+address
geo:0,0?q=business+near+city
```

See http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html for more details.

You build the URI, and pass it to the intent, like this.

```
String uri = "geo:latitude,longitude";
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

You might also want to make sure that the Google Maps application is actually installed on the device, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7116840/347379), so you don't run afoul of devices that don't have Google Maps installed (Amazon Kindle, Barnes & Noble Nook, etc.).

Comment: I used "geo:0,0?q={A postcode}" which worked nicely to show a postcode location